VMSS Predictive Autoscale and AKS
In 2022, several companies released services to autoscale Kubernetes clusters based on predictions. For example, Dysnix released PredictKube in integration with KEDA, and Alibaba launched AHPA. In the same year, Azure Monitor announced predictive autoscale for Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets.
Since VMSS autoscale operates externally to AKS control, I'm wondering if this is Microsoft's response to the increasing demand. If so, wouldn't the VMSS predictive autoscale potentially conflict with AKS autoscale if set to automatic instead of manual? Also, if that's the case, what are Microsoft's best practices for enabling predictive scaling of AKS nodes?
AKS Autoscale

VMSS Predictive Autoscale


The VMSS predictive autoscale and AKS autoscale operate independently of each other, so there should be no conflict if both are set to automatic scaling. Microsoft's best practice for enabling predictive scaling of AKS nodes is to use the cluster autoscaler in conjunction with the VMSS predictive autoscale. The cluster autoscaler monitors the demand for pods and scales the number of nodes in the AKS cluster accordingly. By using both autoscalers together, you can ensure that your AKS cluster and VMSS scale set are both optimized for demand.


VMSS Predictive Autoscale and AKS

The predictive autoscaling in VMSS can be seen as part of   proactive approach to scaling. While AKS autoscaling operates based on real-time metrics at the Kubernetes layer, VMSS predictive autoscaling anticipates future demands by analysing historical data, scaling the underlying VM instances ahead of predicted load.
Conflict between AKS and VMSS autoscaling mechanisms arises when both are set to automatic. AKS’s automatic scaling responds to immediate resource requirements within the cluster, while VMSS predictive autoscaling acts in advance of changes in load. If not correctly aligned, these two autoscaling approaches could lead to over-provisioning.
Azure sync'sAKS autoscaling with VMSS predictive autoscaling by combining AKS’s real-time scaling with VMSS’s predictive capabilities. for further clarification refer below documents.
References:

Scalability considerations for Azure Kubernetes Service environments

Use predictive autoscale to scale out before load demands in virtual machine scale sets

Best practices for performance and scaling for small to medium workloads in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)



According to the Microsoft design recommendations, we should a avoid enabling or edit VMSS scalability settings, and use the cluster autoscale. However, by doing so, we won't use any predictive autoscaling. Is there any other way to use predictive autoscaling with AKS?

Alternative way for predictive autoscaling with AKS would be to use the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA) and the Kubernetes Event-Driven Autoscaler (KEDA) .
Link-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/scenarios/app-platform/aks/scalability#design-recommendations
